# How to sign back in when using signInWithCustomToken?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I used the token generated by my authentication server to sign my users in using `signInWithCustomToken(token)`. Now what I cannot figure out is if they sign out, how will I sign them back in ?

I don't think saving the generated token in the database is a good idea because then I am going to have to give it public access so the user can access it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user signs out. You have to go through the same mechanism you used initially to generate the custom token. Do not save the custom token. Besides it is only valid for a short period of time.

One example is if you are using our own username/password auth system. You ask the user for the username/password, verify it in your own server and then issue the custom token back to the client, client calls signInWithCustomToken and user is signed in. If the user signs out, you have to repeat the process.